# How to send data or extra to a layout or an activity from a TabHost?

Tags: android

I want to send data or extra to an activity from a `TabHost` :

```
public class OngletParcelleListeBatiments extends Activity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private String bien_code;

    public OngletParcelleListeBatiments() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.onglet_parcelle_batiment);

        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.onglets);

        mTabHost.setup();

        Bundle dataSent = getIntent().getExtras();

        bien_code = dataSent.getString("bien_code");

        // first tab
        TabHost.TabSpec parcelle = mTabHost.newTabSpec("parcelle");
        View onglet = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tab_onglets, null);
        TextView label = (TextView) onglet.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
        label.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.parcelle));
        parcelle.setIndicator(onglet);
        parcelle.setContent(R.id.tabContentParcelle); // I want to send data to the activity of this layout
        mTabHost.addTab(parcelle);

        TabHost.TabSpec batiment = mTabHost.newTabSpec("batiments");
        View onglet = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tab_onglets, null);
        TextView label = (TextView) onglet.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
        label.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.titre_liste_batiments));
        batiment.setIndicator(onglet);
        batiment.setContent(R.id.tabContentBatiments); // I want to send data to the activity of this layout
        mTabHost.addTab(batiment);

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

}
```

The layout of the `TabHost` onglet_parcelle_batiment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/onglets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tabContentParcelle" 
                layout="@layout/parcelle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tabContentBatiments"
                layout="@layout/liste_batiments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The included `layout` id=tabContentParcelle :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
    style="@style/ImpotsStyle"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/identification"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/identification"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"
                        >
                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/denomination"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/denomination"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/datePremConstr"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/datePremConstr"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/dateFinConstr"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/dateFinConstr"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/quartier"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/quartier"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:focusable="false" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/ruePpale"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/ruePpale"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen">
                    </Spinner>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/rueSecnd"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/rueSecnd"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen">
                    </Spinner>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/portePpale"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/portePpale"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/porteSecnd"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/porteSecnd"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/superfBatie"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/superfBatie"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/superfNonBatie"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/superfNonBatie"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/superfTotale"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/superfTotale"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/superfPlanim"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/superfPlanim"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fieldMoyenWidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancel"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonWidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_cancel"
                    android:onClick="fermer" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ok"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonWidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_ok"
                    android:onClick="valider" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The included `layout` id=tabContentBatiments :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/ImpotsStyle"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/btnLabelAjouter"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:onClick="addBatiment"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to set the `content` of the `TabSpec` to an `intent` but this crashed the app ! So how to pass data or extra to the two layouts/activities `content` of the `TabHost` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok , I made an old tip to solve it : I created a `public static` class variable in the `Activity` which calls the tabHost activity.